# Higher Order Implicit Runge-Kutta Solver in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration, implicit-methods

Is there an implementation of a higher order Implicit Runge-Kutta solver than Radau (Order 5) in Scipy?

Searching online didn't reveal anything. I have a differential equation system which isn't stable for a reasonable atol with any of the default methods for scipy so I am wondering if anyone has implemented a higher order implicit method.

Comment: Can you distillate your system down in order and complexity while retaining the stiff behavior, so that you can present this simple case here? Or, does your system have other characteristics outside the observed stiffness? Are there points in the domain where the smoothness drops or the system becomes singular or nearly so?